# nhibernate update schema : relationships not removed

Tags: nhibernate, constraints

im using nhibernate (version 3.1.0) with ms compact edition 4.0 and have a 'many to one' relationship for some tables.

works fine, constraints are checked correctly.

i've changed the relationship by adding 'not-found="ignore"' in the hbm.xml, so that i will not have an error when the parent needs a child.

the database is updated by using 'NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate', but the relationship is still there ?!

Anyone an idea how to remove these relationships in an update?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default SchemaUpdate will do everything so that you don't lose your data. Deleting something from your schema may have such an impact. So NHibernate won't do that.

But you can do SchemaExport to recreate all tables with constraints.

Comment: thats not correct. even with all data deleted from the tables, and running the update again, will not remove the constraint from the database. when i do an update, i have more constrains than when i create a empty database, and run the schema update.

Comment: (in my new sw version i have added some 'not-found=ignore' flags, so thats why i see less constraints than an update (which is of coarse strange)